# Cannot read property 'target' of undefined  when trying to access <input> files

Tags: javascript, file-upload, filereader

I'm trying to change file upload image to select or click on image on the same page in this canvas related script.

```
function aFileIsLoaded(e1)
{
        var filename = e1.target.files[0];
        var fr = new FileReader();
fr.onload = function(e2)
{
      backgroundimage = new Image();
      backgroundimage.src=e2.target.result;
     var context = document.getElementById('myCanvas').getContext('2d');
     context.canvas.width = backgroundimage.width;
     context.canvas.height = backgroundimage.height;
     context.drawImage(backgroundimage, 0, 0, backgroundimage.width, backgroundimage.height);


};
    fr.readAsDataURL(filename);
}



window.onload=function(){
var s = document.getElementById("fontsize");
s.value="48";
document.getElementById('loadpicture').addEventListener('change', aFileIsLoaded, false);
backgroundimagemode=NONE;
carpeInit();
update();
}
```

before, this images were called like this,  and files were selected from desktop

```
<input type="file" name="back" id="loadpicture" src="myimage.png" >
```

and now I'm trying to load an image in the same page with this:

```
<img src="myimage.png" name="back" id="loadpicture" onclick="aFileIsLoaded()">
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined
```

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You are calling a custom function:

```
function aFileIsLoaded(e1)
{
        var filename = e1.target.files[0];
```

This function expects an Event object instance, of a file input change event,  to be passed as its first and only argument. You do not pass this parameter *e1* in your *onclick* handler

```
 onclick="aFileIsLoaded()">
```

The workaround is to use DOM look-up to look the element in the question to read its files

```
 var filename = document.getElementById('loadpicture').files[0]
```

As the example lacks HTML code the answer might not be complete.

More information abouts the events

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener